# Is Neodymium Powder Magnetic?

Tags: magnetism

In attempting to make magnetized neodymium (NdFeB) powder, I grinded neodymium magnets into a powderusing a belt sander. However, I found that the magnetic properties of the neodymium had decreased substantially. It would appear that any attempt to grind the magnets into a powder using this method seems to cause the diminishing magnetic field observed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium_magnet .

Is it possible for neodymium (NdFeB) powder to be as magnetic as a solid neodymium (NdFeB) magnet?

Comment: Neodymium powder ≠ powdered neodymium magnet. Neodymium is an element, neodymium magnet is an alloy. Which one you are asking about?

Comment: NdFeB is the type of magnet that I am referring to.